# as3 Creating a raster drawing app. using bitmap data

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, drawing

I have tried many times to create a drawing application using bitmaps, and I have failed everytime. All I want it an application in which the user can draw a black line on bitmapdata. If someone could put together or show me a working example of this, I would be very grateful.

```
 import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var isDrawing:Boolean = false;
var brush:Sprite =new Sprite();
brush.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
brush.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,5);
brush.graphics.endFill();

 var canvasData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(600,400, false);
var canvas:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasData);
addChild(canvas);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrawStart);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrawStop);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);

function onDrawStart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDrawing = true;
}

function onDrawStop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDrawing = false;
}

function render(e:Event):void
{
    if(!isDrawing) return;

    brush.x = mouseX;
    brush.y = mouseY;

    canvasData.draw(brush);
}
```

Here is some code I have that does not work, simply nothing happens (no errors either). Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the upper left corner of your `BitmapData` becoming black once you click? If yes, you should use `matrix` parameter to position `brush` to correct position, instead of moving the brush. `var mat:Matrix=new Matrix(); mat.translate(mouseX,mouseY); canvasData.draw(brush,mat);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did not notice before the dot appearing. I implemented the code you said, and it still doesn't work properly. Whenever I click for the first time, a dot appears in a seemingly random position. if I click again, nothing happens.

Comment: Then, use the event `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` to draw that brush, with that event you'll be able to correctly get coordinates via `e.stageX`,`e.stageY`.